# Restrict Android Studio/Gradle resolving source paths (symlink problem)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, symlink

This may be a bit of a XY problem in that it involves symlinking files into the source tree.  I sometimes do this in development with libraries that are common to a number of application projects. More conventionally they would (and later will) be just .aar imports.  Not doing that simplifies API tweaks on the library in the context of the application code -- an option would be to automate packing and importing the aar, but that is still more of a PITA and means I either run two projects in the IDE at the same time (untried) or else switch between them.

Generally the symlinks are just directories, but currently I am doing it with individual files, and a strange problem has blossomed trying to build the app involving **"Redeclaration"** errors.  This occasionally happens with the directories, but it is usually resolved by a gradle re-sync or an invalidate-and-restart.

To be clear, the problem is one that should not exist and smells very much like a bug:  The "redeclaration" refers *to the symlinked locations* which are **not** in the build tree or project folder -- ie., the redeclaration involves processing the same file twice with different paths.<sup>1</sup>

Frustratingly, invalidate-and-restart did not work with the individual files, so I removed the symlinks and just copied the files in.  No more symlinks, but bizarrely the same problem happens:

```
./gradlew assemble
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /home/devel/Android/lib/droidutil/src/cogware/droidutil/Plexus.kt: (5, 8): Redeclaration: Plexus
e: /home/devel/Android/template/FooDemo/app/src/main/java/cogware/droidutil/Plexus.kt: (5, 8): Redeclaration: Plexus
```

(Same thing using the IDE.) The project folder here is `/home/devel/Android/template/FooDemo`.  `/home/devel/Android/lib/droidutil/src/cogware/droidutil/` is not part of it -- although to be fair there are still other symlinks into it, all gradle needs to do is *follow the explicit path set for it*.  What seems to be happening now is:

- It resolves symlinked paths and uses them not instead of the symlink paths, but *as well as*.
- It even searches around in the resolved paths for files that match names in the proper tree! To explain: After I removed the symlinked files, symlinked directories (which are working fine) remain, but *not* into the `droidutil` directory above.  There is, eg. a `/home/devel/Android/lib/listfilterstack` linked in, and it still manages to find a "Redeclaration error" in `/home/devel/Android/lib/droidutil/src/...`.

The only thing that would make less sense would be if it were searching around the whole filesystem at random.

### Why does it retain this path and how do I get rid of it?

Invalidate-and-restart does not make any difference.  I've tried adding this to app/build.gradle:

```
android { 
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '/home/devel/Android/lib/**'
                srcDirs = [ 'app/src/main/java' ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Which `exclude` apparently has no semantic value there -- same error. Invalidate-and-restart again -- same error.

Short of wiping my hard drive and starting the project again from scratch on another computer in a different time zone, the only thing that has worked is for me to literally *move* `/home/devel/Android/lib` to somewhere completely else so that the path no longer exists.  I should not have to do this.  I should be able to explicitly set where the build tool searches for sources, and not have it unravelling symlinks and prowling around hither-and-thither.

---

1. I miss include guards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a bug, but unfortunately the kind that will probably never be completely fixed:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3982

Not exactly the same context or symptoms, but the takeaway for me is that *gradle was not implemented to deal with symlinks in an intelligent way,* hence:
**Don't use symlinks with gradle.**